# JSCalc. Return values from a list

Tags: calculator

Im trying to return the values from a 'repeating item' input. But 'inputs.value' doesn't work. I think I need to creat a loop and index for every item on the list but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> I think I need to create a loop and index for every item on the list..

Yes. You are right on that. The 'Repeating Item' is internally stored as an object array. So you need to iterate that array to process it. The individual items are objects and hence you will not be available on the `inputs` object directly, but via `inputs.lineitems`, where `lineitems` is the property name of the repeating item prototype.

For example:

You are creating a repeating items list of items which you want to order. So, you have two inputs inside the repeating items prototype, say `itemName` and `itemQuantity`. You name the repeating items property name as `LineItems`. You want to display it as an output table and also display total quantity ordered. The output table is named `Orders` and the total label is named `Total`.

You could then iterate this to process it further, like this:

```
var result = [], totalItems = 0;
```

Where `result` is an array that you would want to map to your output table, and `totalItems` is where you would cache the total quantity.

```
inputs.LineItems.forEach(function(item, idx) { 
  totalItems += item.itemQuantity;
  result.push({ 
    'ItemNumber': idx + 1, 
    'Item': item.itemName, 
    'Quantity': item.itemQuantity
  });
});
```

Where, you are iterating the repeating items via `inputs.LineItems` and increment `total` accordingly . You also prepare the `result` array to map to the `Orders` table later on.

This is what you return:

```
return { 
    Total: totalItems,
    Orders: result
};
```

Where, `Total` is the output label you defined earlier, and `Orders` is the out put table name you defined earlier.

---

Here is a demo for you to understand it better:

https://jscalc.io/calc/YicDJYCSlYTGYFMS

To see the source, just click on the ellipsis (*three dots shown after the 'Powered by JSCalc.io' text*) and click "make a copy".

Hope this helps.